# Struggling with php regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm struggling with what I imagine is quite a simple regex for a preg_match_all() call. I'm looking to mimic the Wikimedia style internal links system which will turn something like this [[link]] into a link.

I'm looking for a regex that will search a string for any example of [[foobar]] and return "foobar" to me. foobar should really be wild.

I've tried the following:

```
<?php
 $content = "Lorem ipsum dolor [[sit]] amet, consectetur adipiscing [[elit]].";
 $links = preg_match_all("[[*]]",$content,$matches);
 print_r($matches);
?>
```

I'm not getting much of anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `[` as `\[` and then match the overall expression with the un-greedy flag `U`.

```
$content = "Lorem ipsum dolor [[sit]] amet, consectetur adipiscing [[elit]].";
$links = preg_match_all("/\[\[(.*)]]/U",$content,$matches);
print_r($matches);

Array(
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => [[sit]]
        [1] => [[elit]]
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => sit
        [1] => elit
    )
)
```

**EDIT**: user ridgerunner pointed out that it's considered bad practice to use the `/U` modifier because it turns all matching quantifiers greedy, including ungreedy ones. The suggested matching code is `(.*?)` instead of what's posted above, and it produces the same equivalent answer.

```
$links = preg_match_all("/\[\[(.*?)]]/",$content,$matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I can't accept for another 10 minutes, just counting down the time

Comment: Appreciate the courtesy. Cheers!

Comment: NEVER USE THE U FLAG! Best practice is to _always_ use the `?` ungreedy modifier on the quantifier itself right in the regex.  There is never a case where the 'U' modifier is required and the only purpose it serves is to confuse. I rarely downvote an answer but until this is fixed, I am giving this answer my downvote. (Fix it and I'll remove my downvote)

Comment: Purpose of my answer was to show where the guy took the latest wrong turn, not to point out when he made a strategic blunder. Appreciate your explanation and respect your downvote, but I won't be threatened into changing an answer.

Comment: Did you know that the 'U' flag also turns ungreedy quantifiers to be greedy? For non-trivial regexes (having a mix of greedy and ungreedy quantifiers), the 'U' flag does nothing but make things _very_ confusing (and bug prone). But don't take my word for it, go read Mastering Regular Expressions 3rd Edition.

Answer (score 4):

`*` alone doesn't mean anything. It's a quantifier, it needs to be with something else. In this case, a dot `.` would do (means "anything"). Also, you can use [lazy quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) instead of greedy ones to stop as soon as you encounter `]]`.
So...

```
$links = preg_match_all("/\[\[(.*?)]]/",$content,$matches);
```

**Edit:**
You have to escape the `[` as they mark the beginning of [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: A possessive quantifier with a negative character set would be more appropriate than lazy quantifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info on ways to go about it.

Comment: Works well. +1 for the `?`. But note @Jacks comment

Comment: @Jack fair enough. Though I think lazy quantifiers will make the regex more efficient than using a negative character class.

Comment: Lazy quantifiers do backtracking, so it shouldn't be used unless necessary.

Comment: @Jack I'll have to disagree. They shouldn't be used in a case where backtracking might happen. If you're sure there won't be, I'd say go for the most efficient - the lazy. Arguably, OP may surely have backtracking, but as it's not sure, I wouldn't throw away the lazy.

Comment: Wondering what's the result of using the `U` modifier with a possessive quantifier though. I'll try that out. Result: the possessive's still greedy, too bad.

Comment: @Loamhoof. You do not seem to understand Jack's point. Using lazy quantifiers means the engine has to check ahead one character before each match, therefore it 'backtracks' one character for each one matched. That is why a greedily-matching negated character class is considered more efficient.

Comment: @MikeM the only test that I was able to find shows otherwise: http://jsperf.com/regex-speed-test-aikloe. You'll notice there is no possessive quantifier (JS eh), but there's no backtracking anyway in this example. I'll be glad if you can provide a better example that proves me wrong or not. (Also, I'm not sure about the backtracking you're talking about in an advanced flavor)

Comment: @MikeM Don't worry I know about the lazy. The test's still quite relevant in my opinion, but I've ran other tests and have to admit that it's indeed quite more slower than I had imagined. Mea culpa. Edit: never mind the link, read the results wrong ._.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all("/\[\[([^\]]*?)\]\]/i",$content,$matches);
```

Comment: The `?` and `i` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following pattern `/\[\[(.*)\]\]/U` :

```
$content = "Lorem ipsum dolor [[sit]] amet, consectetur adipiscing [[elit]].";
$links = preg_match_all("/\[\[(.*)\]\]/U",$content,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Explanation. The regex needs to start and end with a delimiter its the `/`. Square brackets `[` have to be escaped in a regex like `\[`. The content between the brackets must be inside a capture group `(.*)`. At last the ungreedy modifier is been used `U` to make sure that only the content between the nearest brackets will get captured. (remove to see its functionality)